# How to apply global filter on Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a table in my model named Customers with a field IsActive. Whenever I run a query on Customers, only the active customers should be retrieved. I can include the filter in every query, but that doesn't look very. I would like to be able to override the Customers property at the Object Context lever, but I am not sure if this is possible. Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Although a late response, I will put it here so it can help others.

You can also set a condition for your entity in your edmx file. Select your entity and Goto Mapping Details and create a new condition.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do extacty this step programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could declare new property and use it:

```
public partial class MyEntities
{
    public ObjectQuery<User> ActiveCustomers
    {
        get
        {
            return Customers.Where(c => c.IsActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is problem for you. You can put one query inside some function:

```
IEnumerable<Customers> GetActiveCustomers()  
{  
    var activeCustomers =   
    from cust in db.Customers  
    where cust.IsActive == true  
    select cust;  
    return activeCustomers;  
}
```

And call it every time you like. You can even put active customers in some private List or even better ObservableCollection. Then you can query your result again:

```
 var myCustomers =  
 from cust in GetActiveCustomers()  
 where cust.CustomerName == "John"  
 select cust;
```

and that's it.

Answer (score -5):

All you need to do is retrieve all of the customers no matter if they are active or not and then use a

```
foreach(Customer c in Results)
{
if(c.IsActive)
   listofactivecustomers.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: What if after years of the using the software, there are now 100 million inactive users, wouldn't your solution slow down the system ?

Comment: @billy thanks for the down vote. I was unaware that this had to be scalable. I think that if any question asked years ago would have some problems with it. Now I can rest assured that you have the best interests of the future and whatever problems an answer may face. I am glad that you can spend your time to go through each question and answer and make sure it stands up to the test of time.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke Mate, it's just a bad idea - this filtering needs to happen server side. Now, can you delete the bad advice please?