# Entity with default filter on EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have an entity called Client on my .edmx file.

I have to run several linq querys agains it but on all of them, i need a filter (lets say active=1).

I dont want to have a `where c.active == 1` on all my queries, it makes more sense that my entity has a default filter applied. Is it something that can be done?

Or maybe can I have a query as base to an entity instead of a table? (I'm on a database first approach)

I know another solution would be to create a view on the DB and link the entity to the view, but I don't want that either.

Comment: Do you want to modify that entity as well? Do you want to access clients who are not active?

Comment: no, to this application its like if the inactive clients didnt exist

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply global filter on Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624597/how-to-apply-global-filter-on-entity-framework)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6417407/11635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add additional method to your generated Database context:

```
partial class DatabaseContext // same name as your generated context
{
    IQueryable<Client> ActiveClients { get { return Clients.Where(c => c.active == 1); } }
}
```

And use it throughout your code. As it's part of partial class (defined in some other file than your generated context class), it's not affected by codegen tool when you refresh your schema.

Comment: This is ok but it wouldn't work for navigation properties, for example. It is not applied for everything automatically.

Comment: sounds like a good Idea Bartosz. @usr, can you clarify your statment? why wouldnt it work?

Comment: @Diego this would not filter the result you get when you say `Employee e; e.Clients` (assuming 1:n between Employee and Client). This expression would also return inactive ones. I have don'e what Bartosz proposed and I know that the need for this crops up sooner or later.

Comment: got you. But I dont think I'll ned this to be honest

Comment: @usr how did you overcome those problems?

Comment: @Bartosz I never tried for EF, only for L2S where it is basically unsolvable without a custom expression rewriter. My intention was to annotate this answer in the hope that someone else might have a solution.