# Entity Framework How mapping with condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three class Student,Teacher and Document. Student and Teacher may have many Documents

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
} 

//ParentType Student = 1
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

}

//ParentType Teacher = 2
public class Teacher : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; } //Foreign Key
    public int ParentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

I use Entity Framework(Fluent API). For example, I create map for Student and I don't know how to configure Document in student with two Condition `(where parentId = itemId and ParentType = 1)`?

```
public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        ToTable("Student", "dbo");

        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => new {t.ItemId});

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.ItemId).HasColumnName("ItemId");

        Property(t => t.IsDeleted)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnName("IsDeleted");

        Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnName("Name");

        Property(t => t.Surname)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnName("Surname");
    }
```

Comment: in my previous project i use ADO.Net and use attribte [Child(RelationType.OneToMany, "ParentId", "ParentTypeId", 1)] and when creating query i load child Document with where. How can i do with entityFrame?

Comment: Maybe the different methods to use [inheritance with EF](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) will help you to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: It could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493641/entity-with-default-filter-on-ef

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a conditional foreign key in EF just like I am pretty sure you can't have one in most DBMSs (like sql server). You have 2 options:

- Omit that *relationship* from the schema and model and create your join(s) when you need them. You also have to keep this in mind when creating the entities that you have to manually set the key values.
- You could create a `nullable` column per relationship in the `document` entity which is supported. You could add a check constraint in the database to ensure exactly one relationship key has a value (per record).

Comment: Document have foreignKey parentId and student have Primary Key ItemId

Comment: @user3351644 - I understand what you are trying to do, it is not possible. You can't define / map a foreign key that is mapped to multiple entities (a discriminator does not matter).

Comment: Look I have Student (ItemId = 1, Name = John) and Teacher(ItemId = 1, Name = Peter) in Document two Rows(ItemId = 1, ParentId = 1(this John), parentType = 1 and ItemId = 2, ParentId = 1(This Peter), parentType = 2)

Comment: @user3351644 - Again, I get what you want but EF and the databases provider will not let you model that relationship and key constraint.

Comment: @user3351644 - you will have to manually set the key values when you persist changes and write joins for retrieving the related entities when you query the database (see bullet 1 above).